# What are lightweight/mobile options for safely transporting an 11-month-old in a car?

Tags: infant, car-seat, transport

We have an 11-month-old child. She's reaching the upper limit of a baby car-seat. We rely on taxis for transportation. This means that when we go somewhere, we have to take the car-seat with us - we can't leave it in the car while it's parked.

So far we've managed with a baby car-seat that mounts on a folding stroller, but as our child outgrows that, I'm unclear on how we can safely transport her in cars and be able to be mobile at our destination: are there car-seats for infants / toddlers that are compatible with strollers? Or is there another approach that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Have you tried asking the taxi company you use most often if they can send you a taxi with a car seat already installed? Depending on where you live this may be possible or even commonplace. Obviously it rules out hailing a cab on the street, but saves you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Unfortunately not: I'm in Singapore, and there aren't taxis with car seats available - you have to always supply your own. (Or not use a seat - it's commonplace here to see people holding their babies in their arms while travelling, which isn't an approach I'd like to emulate)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have any great options. I don't know of any convertible (toddler) car seats that easily double as a stroller.

Options, however, may include:

- Trying to start/end your journey somewhere it can be stored, like luggage storage at public train stations.
- If you have set time away and use a regular company, can they store the seat for you? I know that in the US some limo companies will store a car seat if you for instance are using them to take you to the airport and using them as pickup when you return.
- [Britax](http://www.britax.com/) has a [device](http://www.britaxusa.com/store/details/accessories/advocate/car-seat-travel-cart) that let you cart a convertible seat around, but it is probably not practical for general walks like a stroller.
- [Diono](http://diono.com/)'s car seats fold 'flat' and you can get shoulder straps, but they weigh a TON. (It also look like they may not be selling their seats in Singapore, so they may not be certified there).
- Can you use another option than taxis? I know that in both US and some countries in Europe car shares are an option - you pay for the use of a car the days you use them.

Comment: Thanks.  If nothing else, it's useful to hear there's no good solution, and stop trying to find one.  Singapore is problematic when it comes to car sharing, I think because of the prohibitive cost of car ownership (licensing for a car is currently around 80,000 dollars, before you think about the cost of the car itself, but that is a digression from the board's purpose so I'll say no more here)

Comment: thinking more about it, I think a Diono seat (if you can get them in Singapore) is the best option. In most countries it is certified up to 80 lbs without top tether, which is an extra install step in a taxi. Because the seat folds up, you could store it in a luggage storage. And if you got a strong back you can carry it as a backpack.

Answer (score -3):

This may depend in some part on the region/locality you are in.  In many locations in the US, at least, car seats are not required when riding in a taxi.  Safety of course is still important, but you can generally still achieve some level of safety with a few simple things:

- Buckle the child with the lap belt, and either bring a [seatbelt adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007EET50G) or put the shoulder harness behind the child.  This is still fairly safe, although not perfect.
- Get something to convert your carseat into a stroller or otherwise gets it rolling. You mentioned a folding stroller adapter; there are also simpler carts, or even [luggage adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JHN3AS) that allow you to put the seat on your rolling luggage.
- Get a booster seat. This is what you will be using eventually anyway (after about age 6-8 depending on size); this still helps at younger ages, and is much more portable than a full size toddler carseat.
- Rental car companies will often rent carseats; in some locations, taxi companies (or perhaps more upscale limo-type companies) may do the same (allow you to reserve one with a carseat for an additional charge).
- You could consider forming a relationship with a particular cabbie and having him/her hold your carseat for you, and then scheduling things with him/her.

Whatever you do, research the laws both in your home locale and in the locales that you travel to.

Comment: a booster seat for an 11 month old? You say yourself it's for age 6-8. And worse, just the seatbelt alone? For a baby who can't even walk yet?